# Question about a polynomial being separable iff $\gcd(f(x),f'(x))=1.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The theorem (proposition 33 pg 547 in Dummit and Foote) states that a polynomial is separable iff its relatively prime to its derivative, i.e. $(f(x),f'(x))=1$. I don't really comprehend why it has to be equal to $1$. It seems like if the gcd was any constant the polynomial would also be separable. Can somebody explain this?

My conjecture is that since any constant gcd would also be a unit in $F[x]$ this is equivalent to having a gcd of $1$. Is this why they do not make the distinction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general ring, gcd is defined only up to associates. Saying the gcd is 1 is equivalent to saying the gcd is $-1$, or any other unit.

Comment: Okay thanks, so basically what I said.

Comment: @Andrew correct.